# "Manually" handling text and cursor position of UITextView breaks when there are multiple lines

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a narrow `UITextView` (about 1 line in height) to which I only add text programmatically, setting the `text` property of it as I click buttons. I also handle the cursor position manually, setting the `selectedRange` as the text changes. All works great as long as I have only one line of text.

When I have two or more lines of text and try to insert text at the first line, the text is inserted correctly and the cursor position is still at the right place but the `UITextView` scrolls to the bottom. When I then add another piece of text at the top it scrolls up to the "correct" position. This pattern then repeats for every entered piece of text at a line other than the last, making the UITextView scroll up and down for every button pressed.

I also tried calling `UITextView scrollRangeToVisible:` passing the selectedRange property as argument after setting the new text. That didn't work either.

I finally tried setting `selectedRange` after a 0.5 s delay after I set the `text`. Then it works as it should, but only after the `UITextView` has first been scrolled down to the bottom for 0.5 s. This seems to indicate that the `setText` method of UITextView is asynchronous in some way, and completes after I have already set `selectedRange` or called `scrollRangeToVisible`, and readjusts the UITextView to what it believes is the desired.

Can anyone tell me what is going on, and how I can get around the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!
When starting in the maze of creating a custom input view, I began implementing `UITextInput` and I found that the `UITextInput` protocol declares many interesting methods. And what is awesome is that `UITextView` implements that protocol. So even though it's not in the immediate `UITextView` API  reference, you can call all `UITextInput` methods on your `UITextView`. For instance `insertText:` (from `UIKeyInput` protocol) and `replaceRange:withText:`. They made it much more flexible to programmatically work with a `UITextView`. Hope this can help someone else too!

Answer (score 0):

The auto scroll behavior of `UITextField`s can be annoying and difficult to harness at times.

Do you need the user to manually edit the text? If not, use a multiline `UILabel`.

If yes, also use a multiline `UILabel` and exchange it on the fly against a `UITextView` once the user taps. Change it back on `didEndEditing`. This techniques has worked well for me in table views.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I was not asking about UITextField, but I guess you mean UITextView, since textfields do not scroll very much. I still would like the caret and the selection handling (when the user drags his finger over the textview) of the UITextView so I don't want to use a label instead. My TextView will basically be first responder all the time, so I won't get any didEndEditing. I guess I will try and build my own text input view by implementing the UITextInput protocol.